# Best way to get URL without subdomains in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, subdomain

I have some strings in JavaScript:

Example: `http://subdomain.domain.com/`

I'm looking for a regex (or similar) expression that can remove the subdomains from the string that leaves: `http://domain.com`

Answer (score -1):

I know this is too late for the answer. However, someone still has the same problem and need to know we have a library [parse-domain](https://www.npmjs.com/package/parse-domain) that works as your expectation

Comment: This is very spam-like. If you want to say your library provides the ability to do this, show an example of your library doing this, and be sure to explain that you have something to do with the library if indeed you do.

Answer (score -3):

```
url = window.location.href; // This will get you url from addressbar.
        var url = "http://subdomain.domain.com/"; // sample for testing purpose. delete this line
        var splitURL = url.split("."); // this will split the url based on .
        console.log("http://"+splitURL[1]+"."+splitURL[2]); //removes the first Part that is stored in splitURL[0] and use only splitURL[1] and splitURL[2]
```